# How to handle multiple ember models for same resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model `user` in `app/models/user.js` with the following:

```
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({
  email:        attr('string'),
  username:     attr('string'),
  firstName:    attr('string'),
  lastName:     attr('string'),
  currency:     attr('string'),
  locale:       attr('string'),
  avatar:       attr('string')
});
```

And I want to update its attributes in different routes:

In http://localhost:4200/account/profile I want to update just:

- firstName
- lastName
- avatar
- username

In http://localhost:4200/account/preferences I want to update just:

- locale
- currency

I'm using ember pod structure so I was thinking to create two models inside those routes with custom adapters and serializers to handle validations and serialize just the attributes that I want for each route.

```
- models
  - user.js
- pods
   - account
     - profile
       - adapter.js
       - controller.js
       - model.js
       - route.js
       - serializer.js
       - template.hbs
     - preferences
       - adapter.js
       - controller.js
       - model.js
       - route.js
       - serializer.js
       - template.hbs
```

But this solution has problems with data binding because I'm not updating the `user` model.

What would it be a good approach for doing this?

Comment: I don't see how the model and rendering a UI to update parts of the model are interrelated. Of course you should make sure that validation is not done on model but on route/controller or component level.

Comment: Please verify my answer if you find my solution was helpful? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you following a kind of mixed structure (classic + pod) in your app?

If you are using `pod-based` layout you can destroy this

```
- models
  - user.js
```

and have corresponding fields in each model of your pod. Say in

`pods/account/profile/model.js`

```
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({
  email: attr('string'),
  username: attr('string'),
  firstName: attr('string'),
  lastName: attr('string'),
  avatar: attr('string')
});
```

`pods/account/preferences/model.js`

```
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';

export default Model.extend({
  currency: attr('string'),
  locale: attr('string')
});
```